# Error:(63, 40) java: incompatible types: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job cannot be converted to org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf

Tags: java, apache, hadoop

I was just running a simple hadooop programm in intellj IDE. but there is an error mentioned when I try to compile

> $Error:(63, 40) java: incompatible types:
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job cannot be converted to
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf

Here is my code for this small program:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class WordCount {

public static class TokenizerMapper
        extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
        while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
            word.set(itr.nextToken());
            context.write(word, one);
        }
    }
}

public static class IntSumReducer
        extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
    private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
                       Context context
    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int sum = 0;
        for (IntWritable val : values) {
            sum += val.get();
        }
        result.set(sum);
        context.write(key, result);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "word count");
    job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
    job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

**Root cause:**

you have used [old API' FileOutputFormat(mapred)](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/FileOutputFormat.html#setOutputPath(org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path)) in your job which takes `JobConf` object as first parameter not `Job`, but `FileInputFormat` method you used from [new API(maprecude)](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/FileOutputFormat.html#setOutputPath(org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path)) which takes `Job` object as first parameter.
(`Job` is also from new API, `JobConf` is from old API)

---

**Solution:**

Change this line in your code:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat;
```

to

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
```

Comment: great - please accept this as an answer(click on the correct sign on left of the up-down arrows)